# Is $(2,1) , (4,1)$ a basis for $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is $(2,1) , (4,1)$ a basis for $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$?

I'm studying free abelian groups. I first showed that for any $n_1, n_2 \in \Bbb Z$ $$n_1(2,1)+n_2(4,1)=0 \\ \Updownarrow \\ n_1=n_2=0$$

But to be a basis I have to show that the set is a generating set. I worked but couldn't find that it generates $\Bbb Z \times  \Bbb Z$. But how would I prove that it doesn't generate $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$. This problem gets me confused.

Comment: How would you obtain $(3,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,y) \in Z×Z$ Now you have to find that exist $n_1$ and $n_2$ integers such that $n_1(2,1)+n_2(4,1) = (x,y).$ By Cramer you have $n_1= \frac{x-4y}{-2}$ and $n_2 = \frac{2y-x}{-2}$ So if you chose $x$ odd those integers don't exist.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote...

Answer (score 2):

For $(2,1);(4,1)$ to be a basis, it must be able to generate every element in the set $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$. If we can find an element which it can't generate then we can conclude it is not a basis.

---

Assume we can generate $(3,1)$.

Therefore, we have $$(3,1)=a(2,1)+b(4,1)$$

That is to say, \begin{align}3&=2a+4b\\
1&=a+b\end{align}

So, we can say \begin{align}3&=2(1-b)+4b\\
3&=2-2b+4b\\
1&=2b\\
b&=\frac 12\\
&\Downarrow\\
a&=1-\frac 12\\
&=\frac 12\end{align}

However, we are working in the integers, so we can't have $\frac12(2,1)=\left(1,\frac 12\right)$ or $\frac 12(4,1)=\left(2,\frac12\right)$ so we have a contradiction

Comment: How you do you make the assumption that it is a basis if we can generate $(3,1)$? Can't there be any other $(x,y)$ that we could generate so my set would be a basis? Why is not generating $(3,1)$ imply not being a basis?

Comment: For it to be a basis, we must be able to generate all elements of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$. If we can find one element which we cannot generate, then it cannot be a basis